# How can I do string formatting in a list?

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, typeerror, networkx

I am using *networkx* and it only takes input in the following way:

```
G.add_edges_from( [ ( '%s' , '%s' ) ] , label = '%s'  % (items2[0] , items2[-1], anothervalue ))
```

Based on my searching, the issue can be summed up as:

```
print (  ['%s']   %   'string'  )
```

The error shown is : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'str'

String format can't work in a list. Is there any workaround as *networkx* input is only in a list format.

Basically I want this to happen:

```
G.add_edges_from( [ ( 'string1' , 'string2' ) ] , label = integar  % (items2[0] , items2[-1], anothervalue ))
```

Comment: Why do you think you need the %s at all? Why can you not use the values directly? Are you following the [docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#edges) or some other page/tutorial?

Comment: You say "it only takes input in the following way".  I've never input something to networkx using something that looked like this.  Can you explain what `items2` is?  There's probably a better way to create the graphs.

Comment: @Joel items2 is just strings. Yes, surely there is. 

Say items2[0] is "something" and 

items2[-1] is "something else"

Comment: So, why not `G.add_edge(  items2[0] , items2[-1])`  ?

Comment: It might help if you explain why you expect it to want input looking like that?

Comment: @Joel Thanks it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This may solve your problem.

```
print (  ['%s'   %   'string']  )
```